# Argument 2:cannot convert from string to int visual studio 2017 c# wpf app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I'm trying to learn C# programming from a book and the code I have been taught to enter so far is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SaveTheHumans
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Random random = new Random();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddEnemy();
    }

    private void AddEnemy()
    {
        ContentControl enemy = new ContentControl();
        enemy.Template = Resources["EnemyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
        AnimateEnemy(enemy, 0, playArea.ActualWidth - 100, "(Canvas.Left)");
        AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100));
        random.Next((int) playArea.ActualHeight - 100, "(Canvas.Top");
        playArea.Children.Add(enemy);

    }

    private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, int v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string propertyToAnimate)
    {
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard() { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = from,
            To = to,
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6))),
        };
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(propertyToAnimate));
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
 }
}
```

It is intended to be a game and the code is setting where enemies can spawn and move around in once the start button is clicked. I've tried searching other posts for problems but none of them have fixed my error. The book in question if it would be of any help is  *Head First C#*
the particular line causing this error is this:

```
random.Next((int) playArea.ActualHeight - 100, "(Canvas.Top");
```

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Next` method expects two `int` as [parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx) so you need to define `"(Canvas.Top"` as int to call the method like :

```
random.Next((int) playArea.ActualHeight - 100, (int) playArea.MaxHeight);
```

Comment: now I get an error when clicking the start button from this line:  private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, int v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

Comment: As a reminder, create a new question for each issue you face and accept the answer that solves the first issue. To answer quickly : the line where you get the error throws an exception because the method is not implemented.